# How to Open OSGi Console in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, osgi

```
$ eclipse -console
```

The above command opens OSGi console and Eclipse IDE in different windows. Is there any options where OSGi Console can be brought inside in console view of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Go to `Run Configuration...` in Eclipse. Double click on OSGi Framework will add a new Run Project for you. In the first view you can add all bundles you want to run. But for now deselect all and click on run. Then an OSGi console will be open in Eclipse.

Comment: This is then the OSGi console for the application. Can also be opened with the parameter "-console" for the "Program arguments". Runs as long as the actual program runs.

Comment: If you're using PDE, see instead @mata's answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can just select the ["Host OSGi Console"](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part4.html) in the Console View. (You might have to install PDE for it to be there.)