# How can I check whether my OSGi Plug-In of my RCP application loaded successfully?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, osgi, rcp, osgi-bundle

I just added a new OSGi Plug-In/bundle to my "Plugins"-folder of my RCP application (NOT the plugins folder of eclipse, it's a Plug-In for the application itself). I want to check whether the Plug-In loaded successfully. How can I do this within the Eclipse IDE?

Unfortunately, I can't look it up under "Help -> About" like in Eclipse, because those buttons don't exist in my RCP application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, you can use the OSGi console. See this question how to open it: [How to Open OSGi Console in Eclipse Juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168195/how-to-open-osgi-console-in-eclipse-juno)

In your RCP application, starting it with `-console` should give you an OSGi console in the terminal where you started it. You probably need to include the plug-in `org.eclipse.equinox.console` for this to work.

Afterwards, you can use the console to show the status of any bundles:

```
osgi> ss org.eclipse.equinox.console
"Framework is launched."


id      State       Bundle
286     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.100.v20130429-0953

osgi> bundle org.eclipse.equinox.console
org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.100.v20130429-0953 [286]
  Id=286, Status=ACTIVE      Data Root=/home/adigulla/packages/eclipse/e4/kepler-SR1/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/286/data
  "Registered Services"
    {java.lang.Object}={osgi.command.function=[comp,component,dis,disAll,disable,disableAll,en,enAll,enable,enableAll,list,ls], osgi.command.scope=equinox, service.id=134}
    {java.lang.Object}={osgi.command.function=[confapply], osgi.command.scope=equinox, service.id=135}
    {java.lang.Object}={osgi.command.function=[ns,pt], osgi.command.scope=equinox, service.id=136}
    {java.lang.Object}={osgi.command.function=[lockApp,schedApp,startApp,stopApp,unlockApp,unschedApp,activeApps,apps], osgi.command.scope=equinox, service.id=137}
    {org.apache.felix.service.command.Converter}={service.id=138}
...
```

Comment: Hello Aaron, thanks for the hint. The "org.eclipse.equinox.console"-bundle is active. What exactly do you mean by starting the application with "-console"? Is this an argument I have to add to my Run configuration?